# Error with external file loading

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, programming-languages

I tried to load an image in the same folder of the flash but it didn't work.

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Stage;


public class engine extends MovieClip {
    var imgRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("cloud.jpg");
    var imgLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var sym:Symbol2= new Symbol2;

    public function engine() {
        imgLoader.load(imgRequest);
        addChild(imgLoader);
        trace(imgLoader);


    }
}
```

}

```
F:\test\engine.as, Line 16  1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.net:URLLoader to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.
```

Could you teach me how to solve this problem? I tried many ways but still didn't get it right T_T

Comment: The thing to remember is that `Loader` is for display elements like images and SWF files, and `URLLoader` is for sending and loading data via HTTP requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    var loader : Loader = new Loader( );
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler );
        loader.load( new URLRequest( "cloud.jpg" ) );



    function completeHandler ( eventOBJ : Event ) : void
    {
        addChild( loader.content );
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use Loader instead of URLLoader.

See this link for reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html

Answer (score 0):

You should check out GreenSock's LoaderMax plugin. It is a very helpful and convenient way to manage external assets in your project:

http://www.greensock.com/loadermax